# Delete data from ListView (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I have 3 java classes (MainActivity, DatabaseOpenHelper and DatabaseAccess)

My add and show buttons work perfectly, but not my delete button. Add adds name and nickname into the database, show shows the list of names in the same layout under the buttons.

**Here is my code in MainActivity.class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText name123, dogName, dogNickname;
    public Button query_button, add_button, show_button, delete_button;
    public TextView result_address;
    public ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> naziv = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name123 = findViewById(R.id.name);
        query_button = findViewById(R.id.query_button);
        result_address = findViewById(R.id.result);

        dogName = findViewById(R.id.et_dogName);
        dogNickname = findViewById(R.id.et_dogNickname);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        show_button = findViewById(R.id.show_button);
        delete_button = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.doglistview);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, naziv);

        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                long result = databaseAccess.add(dogName.getText().toString(), dogNickname.getText().toString());

                if(result > 0){
                    dogName.setText("");
                    dogNickname.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dodaj ime i nadimak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                databaseAccess.close();
            }
        });

        show_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                naziv.clear();

                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                Cursor cnn = databaseAccess.getAllNames();

                while (cnn.moveToNext()){
                    String name = cnn.getString(0);
                    naziv.add(name);
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                databaseAccess.close();
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), naziv.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //setting onclicklistener to query button
        query_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //create the instance of database access class and open database connection
                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                //getting sting value of edittext
                String n = name123.getText().toString();
                String address = databaseAccess.getAddress(n);//getAddress method to get address

                //setting text to result field
                result_address.setText(address);
                databaseAccess.close();
            }
        });

        delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                Integer deletedRows = databaseAccess.deleteData("id_dogName");
                if (deletedRows > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                databaseAccess.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**And here is the code from DatabaseAccess.class:**

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
    static final String NAME = "name_dogName";
    static final String NICKNAME = "nickname_dogName";
    static final String TBNAME = "dogName";
    static final String ROWID = "id_dogName";
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    Cursor c = null;

    //private constructor so that object creation from outside the class is avoided
    private DatabaseAccess(Context context)
    {
        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    //to return the single instance of database
    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //to open the database
    public void open()
    {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //closing the database connection
    public void close()
    {
        if(db!=null)
        {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    //method to query and return the results from database
    //query for address by passing name
    public String getAddress(String name)
    {
        c = db.rawQuery("select nickname_dogName from dogName where name_dogName = ?", new String[]{name});
        String nickname = "";
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            String address = c.getString(0);
            nickname += address;
        }
        return nickname;
    }

    //add
    public long add(String name, String nickname){

        try {

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(NICKNAME, nickname);

            return db.insert(TBNAME, ROWID, contentValues);

        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllNames (){
        String[] columns = {NAME, ROWID, NICKNAME};
        return db.query(TBNAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Integer deleteData (String id){

        return db.delete(TBNAME, "id_dogName", new String[]{id});
    }
}
```

When I click on my phone on the delete button it throws me out of the app. How to correct my code and make the delete button delete a selected item from the list?

Comment: add crash log,  will be helpful in debug.

Comment: @TejuVishwakarma yup, but now I would like to know how to make the delete button work.

Comment: Aren't you able to see your Delete button? whats the exact issue?

Comment: @TejuVishwakarma I can see my button and click on it, but it doesn't delete the selected item. It throws me out of the app, so I did something wrong. The code for my delete button or delete method is not working

Comment: @ViktorMićanović, what we are saying is that you can copy the message in the logcat and paste it here so we can see what happens exactly

Comment: @viktor your app is throwing you out of the app, means your app is crashing. you need to provide log as well.

Comment: However, this comes to my mind now. There is no logic to delete by id, when I want to delete data from the list I selected. So, when I click on the "Show" button it shows me the list with dog names in the database. I want to be able to click on a name, and then click on the "Delete" button.

Answer (score 0):

something wrong in the second argument, your where clause should include `"=?"`

```
public Integer deleteData (String id){
    return db.delete(TBNAME, "id_dogName=?", new String[]{id});
}
```

Comment: However, this comes to my mind now. There is no logic to delete by id, when I want to delete data from the list I selected. So, when I click on the "Show" button it shows me the list with dog names in the database. I want to be able to click on a name, and then click on the "Delete" button.